# How to Mock a class and its methods which are used by another .py

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to mock a class and its method that is used by another class.

My file structure is:

[1] my_animal.py contains `Myclass` and method: `do_bite()`

**my_animal.py**

```python
class Myclass():
    def do_bite(self):
        return 1
```

[2] my_module.py contains `jobMain("")` which is using the method from `my_animal.py`

**my_module.py**

```python
import sys
from my_animal import Myclass

def jobMain(directoryPath):
    result = Myclass()
    if result.do_bite() is None:
        sys.exit(1)  # stop here
```

[3] my_test.py contains the unittest to test `jobMain` in `my_module.py`

**my_test.py**

```python
from my_animal import Myclass

# Try to mock Myclass
@pytest.fixture
def mock_Myclass(monkeypatch):
    """ Mock myclass  """
    monkeypatch.setattr(my_module, "Myclass", MagicMock())

# I tried below code to mock dobite() method, but it was unsuccessfully
# Mock Myclass.dobite to None"""
@pytest.fixture
def mock_dobite(monkeypatch):
    def mock_return(*args, **kwargs):
        with patch('my_animal',dobite) as p:
            instance = p.return_value
            instance.dobite = Mock(return_value = None)
    monkeypatch.setattr(my_module.Myclass, "do_bite", mock_return )

# My unittest to test dobite() method
def test_dobite(mock_Myclass, mock_dobite):
   with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as s_exit:
       jobMain("")
   assert s_exit.type == SystemExit        
   assert s_exit.value.code == 1
```

My question is: How could I mock the return value of the method `do_bite()` to `None` or any other expected value?

Comment: You have a typo in `monkeypatch.settatr()`. It says `dobite` instead of `do_bite`. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it was my typo on that. Let me correct my post.
But the point is, I wonder if there is another way to mock do_bite()?
Since I have tried many ways and all were unsuccessful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fixture is overly complicated, here is what you can use:

```py
import pytest
from unittest import mock

@pytest.fixture
def mock_dobite():
    with mock.patch('my_module.Myclass') as mocked_animal:
        mocked_animal.return_value.do_bite.return_value = None
        yield
```

You patch the class *as it is imported* (see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6)). Because `Myclass` is imported like this:

```
from my_animal import Myclass
```

you have a local reference to the module, which you have to patch.

`mocked_animal` is the mocked class. To get the instance of the class, you have to use `mocked_animal.return_value`. By adding `do_bite.return_value`, you now can set the return value of the method `do_bite`.

Now your test will work like this (note that you need only one fixture parameter):

```py
def test_dobite(mock_dobite):
   with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as s_exit:
       jobMain("")
   assert s_exit.type == SystemExit        
   assert s_exit.value.code == 1
```

Comment: Many Thanksss MrBean Bremen!

Comment: Many Thanksss MrBean Bremen! i have tried and it worked smoothly :)
Btw, "mock.patch" does not work on my pytest, I need to remove the prefix "mock", so for me it looks like this: **with patch('my_module.Myclass') as mocked_animal**

Normally for this concept, I had to implement 2 fixtures with 2 mocks: 1 for Class and 1 for Method itselft :(. And then input it as 2 parameters in my unittest.
But apply your way, Im now I only need to have 1 fixture which includes 2 mocks: Class and method

Again...huge thanks MrBean Bremen :)

Comment: I added the imports to make this clear - you had probably used `from unittest.mock import patch`, which is also OK. Glad I could help!